# How to reload a banner ad from a view's ViewModel?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, admob, ads

I have implemented a pull-to-refresh to my xamarin app. I am using MVVM, and I want to know if and how could I reload/refresh the banner ad that I have in my view, from the Refresh command that my pull-to-refresh raises. Which obviously is in the ViewModel. I searched everywhere but there is not any documentation on this. Also I think that I could manually navigate back and then navigate to that page again, but I don't think that's the most efficient solution.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT1 - I am using the Prism framework in case that helps, I didn't find a way to even reload the entire view, with prism.

Comment: By banner ad do you mean google ad?

Comment: The code of your page / view would be helpful